# Phonegap Build whitelist just won't work

Tags: android, cordova, mobile

I've been trying to get my app to work on Phonegap Build for days now. It works just fine using the iOS emulator on terminal, but when I test it on an Android AJAX requests won't work. Simply won't work.  I've tried many usggestions but nothing seems to work. Here's my config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.areatecnica" version="1.0.9" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>xxx</name>
    <description>
xxx    </description>
    <author email="xx" href="xxx">
xxx
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.1.1" />
  <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true"/>
  <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false"/>
  <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
  <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
    <gap:plugin name="pushwoosh-pgb-plugin" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />

    <icon src="images/icons/icon.png" />
    <icon src="images/icons/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="images/icons/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="images/icons/icon-114.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="images/icons/icon-144.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="images/icons/icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="images/icons/icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="images/icons/icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="images/icons/icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="images/icons/icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxhdpi" />
    <icon src="images/icons/icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxxhdpi" />


<allow-navigation href="*" /> 
<allow-intent href="*" /> 
<access origin="*" /> 

</widget>
```

Comment: If you have spent days on the issue, maybe you could spend minutes on explaining it...

Comment: I did. It simply doesn't complete the request - there is no error, nothing.

Comment: you don't explain what request you try to do, how you build the app, where you test it (device? emulator? android version?), have you checked if you have errors in the logs. You just say "it doesn't work" and expect people to guess what's wrong.